# Bijection between $\mathbb{N}$ and the finite sequence of $\{0,1\}^*$

Tags: set-theory

Every natural number has a binary representation, so the idea of the mapping from $N$ to $\{0,1\}^*$ was using exactly this binary representation. However, mapping from $\{0,1\}^*$ is trickier,  because the sequence can have arbitraily many leading zeros, making this idea no longer a bijective function, I guess?

My next idea was to add a $1$ to each sequence $\{0,1\}^*$, so we do not have leading zeros anymore, and the use the binary transformation $n = a_02^0 + a_12^1 .... a_n2^{n-1}$, where $a_0, ... a_n$ $\in \{0,1\}$. However, let's say we have $01$, adding $1$ gives us $101$, which is $5$ in binary. Now I got no idea how to reverse $5$ to $01$. Those are all just ideas and I would greatly appreciate some hints or advice!

Comment: Why the "*"?${}$

Comment: Is the goal to construct an explicit bijection or just to prove that there is one?  The latter is considerably easier.

Comment: The goal is to construct one and to show it is one

Comment: Just enumerate binary sequences by length and then by lexicographical order: $\epsilon$, $0$, $1$, $00$, $01$, $10$, $11$, $\dots$.